# Azure AD B2C and B2B directory relations

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

I've connect Azure AD B2C to an external IDP using OpenId. The user flow for signup and signin generates an user in my Azure AD.

**Is correct that all users are listed in both Azure AD (B2B) and Azure AD B2C users list?**

The only thing that differentiates them is the "Source" column where B2C users are marked as "Other"

I have done some tests (for example Provisioning with SCIM, or access to SPA App that use Azure for login, or user manipolation with Graph API) and I can treat B2C users as B2B users, I can't understand what the difference is if not in the directory registration method.

Comment: It seems that adding a user to the B2C directory (via graph-api or automatically with signup on a B2C userflow), it's also added to the B2B directory. 

I thought the two directories were split and segregated.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure B2C directory is supposed to be used as a separate AAD directory, isolated from your normal corporate AAD.

B2B users need to be created into your corporate AAD.

The behavior you see is that B2C is build on top of a "normal" AAD, to which you are now inviting (B2B) users. This is not the intended way to use this AAD for managing B2B users.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll see the users through the AAD blade and AAD B2C blade in the same directory. It’s the same data store that both blades access.